# Grid with html/css as body background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a div that contains a grid generated with css, and that div appears behind other div, that contains the UI.
That is that one div in the body appears behind the other div that contains the user interface.
The div that is behind, must contain a grid drawing using CSS.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    #divcontainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -999;
        background-color: #bababa;
    }

    #divinnercontainer {
        width: 10%;
        height: 20%;
        outline: 1px solid;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="divcontainer">
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
    <div class="divinnercontainer"></div>
</div>

<div style="z-index:999">
  <!-- UI -->
</div>
```

This is my code, but I don't see any grid, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write something in your divs.

Comment: Change `#divcontainer`/`#divinnercontainer` to `.divcontainer`/`.divinnercontainer` in your css

Comment: @HamzaZafeer OP want a grid, not text

Comment: @LGSon I think he meant that divs with no content will not show up unless they have at least some padding or min-height/height defined.

Comment: @Aziz And they have ... apply my first comment and they show

Comment: @LGSon yes but for his rules to work, OP needs to add `html, body {height:100%}` otherwise percentage height will not work properly

Comment: @Aziz Not needed, it works with the fix I commented ... if you can't see it, test the code before say it doesn't work ... OP uses `position: absolute`, hence work as is

Comment: @LGSon wow, I did not know that using `position:absolute` works with percentage height of viewport without setting body/html to 100% height

Comment: @Aziz Sorry .. that might sounded a little harsh :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you use `#divcontainer` and `#divinnercontainer` instead of `.divcontainer` and `.divinnercontainer`.

Answer (score 0):

you mixed up css classes with css ids.

You simply need to change 
    #divcontainer {
        ...
    }

```
#divinnercontainer {
    ...
}
```

to
    .divcontainer {
        ....
    }

```
.divinnercontainer {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

# is for id not for class

```
.divcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -999;
    background-color: #bababa;
}

.divinnercontainer {
    width: 10%;
    height: 20%;
    outline: 1px solid;
    float: left;
}
```

## [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grwpVw)

Answer (score 0):

in css is `#divinnercontainer`, but you call a `divinnercontainer` as a class in html

Answer (score 0):

Your just need to fix the class name in your css :

`#divcontainer` **to** `.divcontainer`

`#divinnercontainer` **to** `.divinnercontainer`